# Notation of an infinite union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there any difference between:

$$
\bigcup_{n =1}^\infty a_{n} \\
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{n} 
$$

From my understanding they both define an infinite union. Is this correct?

Comment: The first one suppose that you take the strictly positive integers. The second one includes also $a_0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that convention is not universal. Often, the natural numbers exclude $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm French and in France $\mathbb N$ always includes $0$. Do you mean that in English the same symbol can or not include $0$?

Comment: There is a subtle difference.  The second allows for the subscripts to be other things, such as negative integers, reals, etc.  However, only the natural subscripts appear in the union.  The first presupposes that this is not possible.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net unfortunately, yes.  It depends on the author.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net There is a difference between French natural and English natural :)

Comment: .....Naturally!

Comment: We can say that there is no difference between French and English naturals, since the difference is $0$. EDIT: there is a difference, because the difference equals $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you define $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$, then yes: the two sets you've defined are identical, and describe the same infinite union.

Note that some define $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$

Answer (score 3):

The only difference it that it sometimes unclear if you consider $0$
as an element of $\mathbb{N}$ so that 
$$
\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}
$$

or that 
$$
\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}
$$

The first notation removes this ambiguity and makes things more clear.

At the end - I would say that its a matter of preference and convention,
I have seen both used many times interchangeably

Comment: @vadim123 - whoops, I saw to many [infinite] sums this week :P